# mongoose collection names is created with an ending 's'

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

when I define a mongoose schema like this ..

```
const Rental = mongoose.model('Rental', new mongoose.Schema({
```

a collection called "rentals" is created, why isn't it created with name "Rental"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a custom collection name, you can send it as the 3rd argument to `mongoose.model()`

```js
const Rental = mongoose.model("Rental", rentalSchema, "rental");
```

Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model